# How to link Amazon Certificate with neo4j instance running on EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j, certificate

I've created a neo4j database running on an EC2 server using the [aws marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B071P26C9D), and an A record for that server elastic IP in route 53, and it's working:

`http://[URL]:7474`:
[image]

`http*s*://[URL]:7473`:
[image]

So I have no idea how to setup a matching certificate (I have an approved amazon certificate) found a few tutorials that explain how to do that with nginx and apache, but none for neo4j.

help will be very much appreciated.
Tomer.

Comment: Aws certificate manager only applies to specific aws services (load balencer, cloudfront etc) - it's not a general purpose cert you can download and install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted the same question on neo4j community and got an answer from David Allen.

Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/neo4j/getting-certificates-for-neo4j-with-letsencrypt-a8d05c415bbd) to see how to install a certificate with Let's encrypt.